# Number of person to the session

Tags: opentok

Is there away to know how many person connects to a session? 
I wish to implement a mechanism where only two persons are allowed to connect, and if there is more than two, an alert will be shown.

Comment: In which case? What is your question? Which programming language?

Comment: What I am refer to is the opentok api (as tag), where the session refer to the video session of opentok.

Answer (score 3):

When you get a sessionConnected event, you get an array of connections telling you the number of people in the session. http://www.tokbox.com/opentok/docs/js/reference/SessionConnectEvent.html

After you are connected, everytime someone joins the session, you get [ConnectionEvents](http://www.tokbox.com/opentok/docs/js/reference/ConnectionEvent.html) for people leaving and joining the session.

These events can give you an accurate count of the # of connections in the session at any given time

Comment: Links are deprecated

Comment: Here is the new link for ConnectionCreated https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/ConnectionEvent.html